# Did't get month name in x axis

Tags: javascript, morris.js

I got a weird problem. I'm using morris js for line chart [here is my code](http://jsbin.com/bebipojasepo/1/edit)

I'm not getting second month name if I've two month data in which first month is 31 days. e.g. If i've August and September data, then it doesn't display September in x-axis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The name of your months are too long.

For exemple, replace "September" with "Septem", you will show it on the right.

The solution for showing all months, is to change the Angle of label : try to put "xLabelAngle: 45" in the option, or try to reduce the name of the months :

```
 var monthNames = ["","Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"];
```